# How to lock an iPhone programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, password-protection

I use iOS 8 and need to create a simple application on Xcode with a couple buttons on the main view.

How can I lock the iphone screen (with password) from my own application?

For example, is it possible to lock the screen if the user presses the wrong button?

Answer (score 0):

You can't lock the iphone from your application. There is no code snippet provided by apple doc.

Comment: Can i lock my Application? for example need to enter a password to continue.

Comment: What do you mean ? you can insert simple transparent view but when user will press home button your app will be on background and you cannot do anything about home button.